# Do powerful IDEs make me lazy?

Tags: visual-studio

I feel much comfort when coding in Visual Studio IDE. The auto-complete etc makes coding much faster and makes me lazier.

I just felt lost when coding in other not-so-powerful IDE like Android/Java in Eclipse, and notepad for Ruby and Rails.

Am I lazy? Do you have the same feeling?

Maybe my question should be why do other IDEs bring such powerful things?

Comment: you should try netbeans seriously

Comment: this doesn't really belong here, try http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but can't for the life of me find it. Maybe it was deleted already for being completely subjective.

Comment: @gnovice: I was thinking the same thing.  The closest I can find is [How to wean oneself from IDE to text editor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085165/how-to-wean-oneself-from-ide-to-text-editor)  I'm *sure* someone asked if people lean too heavily on IDEs before though.

Answer (score 10):

It's not a matter of laziness, it's a matter of efficiency.

Do you feel lazy by coding in a high level language rather than assembler (or binary)? I don't.

Do you feel lazy driving your car across the country rather than cycling? I don't (for a start, the old ticker probably wouldn't hold out).

Anyway, you make laziness sound like a *bad* thing. I'm all for doing things in an easier way - it gets it done faster and allows me to spend more time with the family.

Comment: +1 I absolutely love your last paragraph.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I, for simple projects, sometimes find `vim` to be a much more efficient way to go about programming. If I'm doing enterprise development however, an IDE would likely be my choice.

Answer (score 2):

Some say laziness is one of the [three virtues of a programmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Wall#Virtues_of_a_programmer).

Comment: See also: [http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/8269/the-virtues-of-laziness-impatience-and-hubris](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/8269/the-virtues-of-laziness-impatience-and-hubris)

Answer (score 0):

You are not lazy just because you prefer using an oven rather than lighting a bonfire.

Answer (score 0):

You could call it laziness, not having to indent every line, complete every statement, or have to reference back for the right parameter or class member when it is staring you in the face whenever you type a `.` or `->`.

But I would think that it is a major relief, wouldn't you agree? I mean, how can a three-fold productivity increase possibly be a bad thing. And so long as you don't forget how to indent, or add a final `)`, then you have nothing to worry about.

So my advice, appreciate it!

Oh, and lazy is usually used to mean not getting enough exercise. Faster coding means more time to take a jog, so in a way, it is making you less lazy :).